# React defaultProps not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't get defaultProps to work.

```
export default class MyClass extends Component{
  static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    field: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    field: { value: '', errors: [] }
  }

  render() {
    // blah blah
  }
}
```

I have code that relies on `this.props.field.value` and `this.props.field.errors.length` and all my tests are blowing up with `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.field.errors.length')`, shouldn't my default props give it a default value? Initially, my `field` prop is an empty object.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Initially, my `field` prop is an empty object.

Default props are only used if no value is passed for the prop. It is is shallow merge, not a deep merge.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) (emphasis mine):

> The result of `getDefaultProps()` will be cached and used to ensure that `this.props.value` will have a value **if it was not specified by the parent component**.

Comment: Should have RTFM a bit more carefully, will have to rethink my approach.

Comment: this is the key point "Default props are only used if no value is passed for the prop. It is is shallow merge, not a deep merge."

Comment: It seems that link reference is outdated. Please refer to this page instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix isRequire with defaultProps. If you give isRequired to field the defaultProps will be ignored.

This should work:

```
static propTypes = { 
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
  field: React.PropTypes.object 
}; 
 static defaultProps = { 
  field: { value: '', errors: [] }
};
```

Comment: That's not really true. Both can be combined

Comment: @davesnx  If you set isRequired means you'll always provide that prop! So you don't need a default :)

Comment: Not really, the propTypes validation run after defaultProps. `isRequired` would log the error, if you don't a defaultProp or you don't pass a prop.

Check this example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-galileo-w707r?fontsize=14